# How to tell AzCopy linux batch to overwrite files?

Tags: azcopy

In azcopy linux version how do we tell Yes to a prompt when part of a script. in the windows version of azcopy it was /Y. what is it the similar parameter for linux version?

Answer (score 1):

Try running azcopy --help and you should get a list of options. My guess is azcopy -y.